# How to change url href in javascript based on page contents?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Here's my javascript part:

```
    function dateCheckThree() 
{   
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay()
    var lukeTre = document.getElementById("Luke3");
    if (n === 2)
    {
        lukeTre.href="home.html";
        confirm("Sorry, you gotta wait untill 3.Desember to enter this page.")  
    }
}
```

this is my html part:

```
    <a href="Luke3.html" id="Luke3" onClick="dateCheckThree()">
    <div-1c> 3 </div-1c>
    </a>
```

NOTE: The Javascript sentenece is true just for testing purposes.
When i click the link, I get directed to Luke3.html

Comment: You need to prevent the default action for the link before changing its `href`. Otherwise, when clicked it will follow the current `href` and ignore your click event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prevent the default behavior of anchor tag as :

```
 function dateCheckThree(e) 
{   

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay()
    var lukeTre = document.getElementById("Luke3");
    if (n === 2 )
    {
       e.preventDefault();
       alert("Sorry, you gotta wait untill 3.Desember to enter this page.")
       lukeTre.href="home.html";

    }
}
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` should be inside the `if` condition. He wants to redirect if `n != 2`

Comment: call onClick as :  onClick="dateCheckThree(event)"

Comment: also make sure there is an event param in function definition as dateCheckThree(e)

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm before redirect, and get the value if you want to confirm.
But i think, you want to use `alert` not `confirm`.

```
var redirect = confirm("Sorry, you gotta wait untill 3.Desember to enter this page.");
if (redirect) {
    lukeTre.href = "home.html";
}
```

So I think, what you want something like this (overwrite the condition):

```
if (n === 2) {
    lukeTre.href = "home.html";
} else {
    alert("Sorry, you gotta wait untill 3.Desember to enter this page.");
}
```